# What class entries should I use to throw non-default exceptions from a C extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension

In my C extension, I can throw a PHP exception to the calling function with `zend_throw_exception`. The first parameter to that function is a `zend_class_entry` that specifies what type of exception to throw. I know from the documentation in `zend_exceptions.h` that I can use `zend_exception_get_default()` to use the default exception type.

But, it also says that I can pass a derived class. Where can I find the class entries for the derived built in exceptions, such as `InvalidArgumentException`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the exceptions are defined in source code here;

```
 php-5.5.15/ext/spl/spl_exceptions.h
```

and can be found here when you install the devel package (e.g `yum install php-devel` on fedora);

```
 /usr/include/php/ext/spl/spl_exceptions.h
```

and contains the following;

```
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_LogicException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_BadFunctionCallException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_BadMethodCallException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_DomainException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_InvalidArgumentException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_LengthException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_OutOfRangeException;

extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_RuntimeException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_OutOfBoundsException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_OverflowException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_RangeException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_UnderflowException;
extern PHPAPI zend_class_entry *spl_ce_UnexpectedValueException;
```

and can according to the unit test be thrown like;

```
zend_throw_exception_ex(spl_ce_InvalidArgumentException, 0 TSRMLS_CC, "array size cannot be less than zero");
```